# How can I read all data from the XML file using TinyXML

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I want to read XML-data using TinyXML. I have the following XML-file:

```html
<weatherdata>
 <location>
  <name>Vlaardingen</name>
  <type/>
  <country>NL</country>
  <timezone/>
  <location altitude="0"
    latitude="51.912498"
    longitude="4.34167"
    geobase="geonames"
    geobaseid="2745467"/>
 </location>
 <credit/>
 <meta>
  <lastupdate/>
  <calctime>0.0152</calctime>
  <nextupdate/>
 </meta>
 <sun rise="2016-02-23T06:40:58"
   set="2016-02-23T17:11:47"/>
 <forecast>
  <time day="2016-02-23">
   <symbol number="500"
     name="lichte regen"
     var="10d"/>
   <precipitation/>
   <windDirection deg="316"
     code="NW"
     name="Northwest"/>
   <windSpeed mps="9.01"
     name="Fresh Breeze"/>
   <temperature day="6.06"
     min="5.57"
     max="6.06"
     night="5.66"
     eve="5.57"
     morn="6.06"/>
   <pressure unit="hPa"
     value="1027.72"/>
   <humidity value="96"
     unit="%"/>
   <clouds value="clear sky"
     all="8"
     unit="%"/>
  </time>
  <time day="2016-02-24">
   <symbol number="501"
     name="matige regen"
     var="10d"/>
   <precipitation value="3.15"
     type="rain"/>
   <windDirection deg="283"
     code="WNW"
     name="West-northwest"/>
   <windSpeed mps="6.21"
     name="Moderate breeze"/>
   <temperature day="4.98"
     min="4.17"
     max="5.11"
     night="4.17"
     eve="4.85"
     morn="4.32"/>
   <pressure unit="hPa"
     value="1030.97"/>
   <humidity value="100"
     unit="%"/>
   <clouds value="scattered clouds"
     all="48"
     unit="%"/>
  </time>
  <time day="2016-02-25">
   <symbol number="500"
     name="lichte regen"
     var="10d"/>
   <precipitation value="1.23"
     type="rain"/>
   <windDirection deg="295"
     code="WNW"
     name="West-northwest"/>
   <windSpeed mps="5.71"
     name="Moderate breeze"/>
   <temperature day="5.43"
     min="4.92"
     max="5.48"
     night="5.34"
     eve="5.48"
     morn="4.92"/>
   <pressure unit="hPa"
     value="1026.18"/>
   <humidity value="100"
     unit="%"/>
   <clouds value="broken clouds"
     all="68"
     unit="%"/>
  </time>
 </forecast>
</weatherdata>
```

And the following C++ code:

```
    for(TiXmlElement* e = elem->FirstChildElement("time"); e != NULL; e = e->FirstChildElement("symbol"))
        {
            cout << "Got symbol" << endl;

            attr = e->Attribute("var");
            if(attr != NULL)
                cout << "Got var " << attr << endl;
            attr = e->Attribute("name");
            if(attr != NULL)
                cout << "Got name " << attr << endl;
                attr = e->Attribute("number");
            if(attr != NULL)
                cout << "Got number " << attr << endl;
        }
```

My question is: How can I change this so all of the 'symbol' data from the three days gets read and displayed?

Greetings,

Don

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterating clause of your `for` statement is wrong. That needs to iterate the `time` elements, and for each `time` element you must get it's child `symbol` element.

```
for (TiXmlElement* e = elem->FirstChildElement("time"); e != NULL; e = e->NextSiblingElement("time"))
{
    TiXmlElement* t = e->FirstChildElement("symbol");
    if (t)
    {
        const char *a1 = t->Attribute("var");
        const char *a2 = t->Attribute("name");
        const char *a3 = t->Attribute("number");

        if (a1)
            cout << "Got var " << a1 << "\n";
        if (a2)
            cout << "Got name " << a2 << "\n";
        if (a3)
            cout << "Got number " << a3 << "\n";
    }
}
```